# Alignment problem in creating table

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table using the following code under two column ieeetransaction class. However, I am not being able to align the attributes properly due to their heterogeneous size. Please help.

```
%Table packages
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}



 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}
                {\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                            >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.5in}
                             >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.2in}
                             }
\toprule
\thead{ID} &\thead{AGE/Gender} & \thead{Earlier\\Fall} & \thead{Known attributes}\\
\midrule\\
\textbf{1} & 70/M & No & osteoarthritis; low back pain\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{2} & 75/F & No & Right knee prosthesis\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{3} & 78/M & Yes & Meniscus surgery in both knees\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{4} & 80/F & No & Anemia; pacemaker; left knee pain\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{5} & 82/M & Yes & Heart surgery. Lower limbs weakness\\
\addlinespace
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabularx}
  \caption{Initial attributes}\label{volunteers}
\end{table}
```

The present output looks like
[image]

Comment: As always here, please extend your example to form a full but minimal examples that others can just copy and test as is. That often makes people more inclined to have a look at the problem.

Comment: BTW: why are you using `tabularx` and no `X` columns? That basically means you might as well use `tabular`, and where does `\thead` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

- Please always provide MWE (Minimal working Example) which reproduce your problem
- `tabularx` table had to have at least one column of `X` or from it derived type
- In IEEEtran article caption had to be on top of tables

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Initial attributes}
\label{volunteers}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\bfseries}c c c L }
    \toprule
\thead{ID} &\thead{AGE/\\ Gender} & \thead{Earlier\\Fall} & \thead{Known\\ attributes}\\
    \midrule
1   & 70/M & No & osteoarthritis; low back pain\\
    \addlinespace
2   & 75/F & No & Right knee prosthesis\\
    \addlinespace
3   & 78/M & Yes & Meniscus surgery in both knees\\
    \addlinespace
4   & 80/F & No & Anemia; pacemaker; left knee pain\\
    \addlinespace
5   & 82/M & Yes & Heart surgery. Lower limbs weakness\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Since you use`makecell` package, your table can be also write as:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{3pt}  % <--- new
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \makegapedcells  % <--- new
\caption{Initial attributes}
\label{volunteers}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ >{\bfseries}c c c L }
    \toprule
\thead{ID} &\thead{AGE/\\ Gender} & \thead{Earlier\\Fall} & \thead{Known\\ attributes}\\
    \midrule
1   & 70/M & No & osteoarthritis; low back pain\\
2   & 75/F & No & Right knee prosthesis\\
3   & 78/M & Yes & Meniscus surgery in both knees\\
4   & 80/F & No & Anemia; pacemaker; left knee pain\\
5   & 82/M & Yes & Heart surgery. Lower limbs weakness\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Result is very similar as before.

**Edit:**
Regarding OP comment: you can make table narrower by using `tabular` table instead of`tabularx` and using column `l` instead of `L`:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\setlength{\rotFPtop}{0pt plus 1fil}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}

\usepackage{lipsum}  % for dummy text filler

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\caption{Initial attributes}
\label{volunteers}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}c c c l }
    \toprule
\thead{ID} &\thead{AGE/\\ Gender} & \thead{Earlier\\Fall} & \thead{Known\\ attributes}\\
    \midrule
1   & 70/M & No & osteoarthritis; low back pain\\
    \addlinespace
2   & 75/F & No & Right knee prosthesis\\
    \addlinespace
3   & 78/M & Yes & Meniscus surgery in both knees\\
    \addlinespace
4   & 80/F & No & Anemia; pacemaker; left knee pain\\
    \addlinespace
5   & 82/M & Yes & Heart surgery. Lower limbs weakness\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect output using makecell.  Just the values under known attributes should go a little right. Can it be done? I am marking it as answer though.

Comment: @Bukaida, no, nut you can make table narrower. Instead of `tabularx` and `L` column use `tabular` and `l column`. See edited answer.